# found nil when reading accelerometer data

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer

I am having trouble using the accelerometer and I don't understand why I am not able to read the data:

I check if the accelerometer is available:

```
if self.motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true {
```

I start the accelerometer updates:

```
self.motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
```

Then i try to read the data but i get an error:

```
println("data.acceleration.x is: \(self.motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x)")
```

unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why is that happening?

(If i use the startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue it works but the updates are too slow)

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`accelerometerData` can be `nil` if none is available.  It is declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional `CMAccelerometerData!`, so you should check for `nil` before using it:

```
if self.motionManager.accelerometerData != nil {
    // Got it
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The error is not happening now, but I am not getting any data. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure.  If you've called `startAccelerometerUpdates()` then it should work once some data is available.

Comment: yeah, that's what i was thinking. but nothing is coming. unbelievable

Answer (score 0):

**I'm assuming self.motionManager has an optional postfix (i.e ?)** 
 - *You should safely unwrap variables like this, to avoid ay unexpected booboos*

```
var motionManager : CMAccelerometerData?

if let motionManager = self.motionManager {
    println("my motion manager is \(self.motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration.x)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is giving me the following error:
"Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"

Comment: Ah, that means your motion manager has already been unwrapped. @MaRco85, instantiate it with the ? and not the !. then unwrap it with the if let statement.